# Adview not visible when added to layout with a listview

Tags: android, listview, adview

I'm trying to add an adView to my layout with a listView but for some reason the adview doesn't show up. It works on the other activities but doesn't show up on the one with the listView on it.
This is the code I'm using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

  <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I've always found layouts a bit tricky. For the listView have you tried setting the `android:layout_width` to match parent? I've often found I've had to fiddle around with these parameters in various XML objects. Also try taking out (temporarily) the ListView if possible and see if the ad shows up.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the list view is set to fill parent. so it is taking the whole screen, and pushing the adview off.
There are two solutions at least:
Easiest, 
add android:layoutWeight ="1" to each node. This tells them to share the space

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

  <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Another approach is to use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout instead of a linear Layout, so that the Views can either overlap each other or be positioned relative to each other. I would suggest a RelativeLayout, so that the ad does not cover part of your ListView. And then use android:layout_below="@id/adView"  to position your ListView below the adView.